# How to enable service controls for Database Engine in SSMS Object Explorer?

Tags: sql-server

In SSMS Object Explorer when you right-click on the server it shows a context menu with service control menu items.  The Start/stop/Restart menu commands are gray and disabled.

[image]

What setting controls the MENU items so that start / stop can be selected or not?

I need to delegate SQL server operation to a user who is not an administrator.  This user must have the SQL server restart feature enabled.

I created a test environment (Win10, SQL Server Express, SSMS). I created a test SQL Login in SSMS without giving any additional permissions (just default).

In the test environment MSSMS Object Explorer right-click to open a popup window. Start / stop / Restart menus item are not grayed, ENABLED!. Why? What settings depending on the, the MENU item (start / stop) can be selected or not.

In the test environment, it works the other way around. I can't delete the right. Can you help me with what the setting depends on? Where do I look for the problem? Windows UAC? SQL Server authorization settings?

Comment: Why do you want this? Is restarting the SQL server a solution to "Why is our line of business application slow again today"?

Comment: Because we only run windows server. We delegate the MS SQL operation task to the person responsible for it. Data is handled by another organization. (backup/restor, restart , etc ..)

Comment: I'm just wondering how often you need to restart SQL server that you'll have to appoint a non-system administrator/DBA to do so.

Comment: The server is rarely restarted, but the option must be provided.
Now the responsibilities need to be separated from the windows administrator task and the DBA administrator task.
(where a DBA administrator should not be windows administrator)

Comment: I would be highly surprised if SSMS implements anything more complicated than "check if the user is a Windows administrator", as that's what you need to be by default. This has nothing to do with SQL Server itself (after all, SQL Server can't check for permissions to start it *before it's started*), just the Windows service permissions. Note that while you *can* grant the right to stop or start a service to non-admins through the security descriptor (through `sc.exe sdset`) it's quite improbable that SSMS actually checks the security descriptor, so you'd need the command line anyway.